# javascript to read mouse position and write to a file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the coordinates of the mouse pointer when clicked on an image on a HTML page, the user has to click on the image and i want to get the coordinates of the clicked position using javascript and also to write to a file on the server itself. I'm using site44 to host from my dropbox account. I am not able to write the coordinates to a file.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>image click test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function coord()
{
var x;
var y;
x=event.offsetX; 
y=event.offsetY;
ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var file = object.CreateTextFile("hello.txt",false);
file.WriteLine(x);
file.WriteLine("by");
file.WriteLine(y); 
file.Close();
}
</script>
</head>

<body onclick="coord()">This is a sample image, please click anywhere on the image. But ensure you click only once.<br>
<img src="index_catfish.jpg" alt="Click Image" usemap="#imageclick"/>
<map name="imageclick">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Browser's JS implementation can not write to local files directly. The only way is to store data in cookies or in localStorage (if it's supported by browser).

Comment: IE can, with ActiveXObject.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I didn't know that IE is also counted as a browser and ActiveX has relation to modern web.

Comment: Its older versions like IE8 and IE9 are still widely used in industry. They are almost dead for single users. But users with WinXp, they are the top, of IE the versions.